# Hyperlink to a network share

Tags: html, outlook

My scenario is this:

I have two network shares (on the same network) that I would like to construct them as a A HREF network share. I tried to make it work with all the solutions given here but couldn't succeeed. These A HREF links are generated on the fly thru a application and sent as a HTML Outlook e-mail. I wanted the link to look like this in the Outlook HTML e-mail.

\\remote_machine_name\sharename1\Windows\notepad.exe \\remote_machine_name\sharename2\SCANDISK.acc

So, all I need is make notepad.exe open on the remote machine along with SCANDISK.acc open on the same remote machine and as a input to notepad.exe. Please note that the remote machines are same both for notepad.exe and for the .acc file but the share names are different.

Btw, I'm also thinking of another possibility of generating javascript code on the fly from the application and take the .acc file as an input and in the javascript method, open notepad.exe and input .acc file to it. Will this work?

As a side note, whenever I click on the .acc file link in the HTML Outlook e-mail, I'm getting a warning from Outlook with a dialog that shows (Open, Save and Cancel).

Please help.

Comment: I am still not clear on what you are trying to do... Are you just having problems making an HTML link to the network share, or is there something else you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
file://///servername/sharename/path/to/file/file.ext
```

There are five slashes after file: and they mean: `///` for the file protocol and `//` for the path to the server. A normal windows path would be like this:

```
\\servername\sharename\path\to\file\file.ext
```

All you need to do is reverse the slashes and append it to `file:///`

Comment: I quickly pressed Enter key. The solution is not working. I tried to just try with notepad.exe to see if it opens by pressing a link from a local html file. I did this:

Comment: <a href="file://///machine-name/share1/Windows/notepad.exe">Link2</a>. Clicking on the link shows me "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". Next, I opened the source for the html from the browser and copied the link and changed the slashes to forward slashes and it works. So, from the HTML page it is not working. I also tried this from Safari and it says "file Not found". But the file exists and share also exists.

Comment: Does \\machine-name\share1\Windows\notepad.exe work from explorer?

Comment: This solved an issue for me... providing a link to a network share within an HTML email that will be viewed in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Weird answer that works for on new Edge

Im new to HTML and coding in general but i got this to work using this code
make sure you add (<)p(>)(<)a(>) but without () and before href
cant show it all together otherwise it will not show the code on here
href="\server\folder\location" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">test

The code is a website link opener that will open said folder in a new browser tab.
"test" being the visual hyperlink name that users will click on. This should work on cloud drives in your intranet as well local drives.